# Quiero poder validar lo que un usuario ingresa

Tags: python, objeto

estoy haciendo un programa para que cuando un usuario me ingrese el nombre de una provincia, este programa vaya a un txt donde estan almacenadas las provincias con algunos datos. Ahora bien, no solo necesito validar que esa provincia existe sino que tambien tiene que mostrar en pantalla cual es el valor que le corresponde para casos totales

```
import re

class Pais:
    def __init__(self,nombre,contagiosTotales, contagiosDiarios, contagiosActivos, muertesTotales, muertesDiarias, vacunasAplicadas, vacunasSinAplicar, vacunasTotales):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.contagiosTotales = contagiosTotales
        self.contagiosDiarios = contagiosDiarios
        self.contagiosActivos = contagiosActivos
        self.muertesTotales = muertesTotales
        self.muertesDiarias = muertesDiarias
        self.vacunasAplicadas = vacunasAplicadas
        self.vacunasSinAplicar = vacunasSinAplicar
        self.vacunasTotales = vacunasTotales

class Provincia(Pais):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def contagiosTotales():
        provincias = []
        f = open('covid.txt', 'r')
        f.read()
        provincia = input("Ingrese el nombre de la provincia que desea:")
        for e in f:
            if provincia == e.find(provincia):
                print("Es verdadero")
            else:
                print("No existe")
        for e in f:
            provincias.append(e)
            print("Agregado")
        f.close()
        regex = re.compile(r'\|(\w+\d+)+?')
        for prov in provincias:
            if provincia in prov:
                casos = re.findall(regex, prov)
                casos = sum([ int(caso) for caso in casos])
                print(casos)
    def agregarProvincia(self):
        self.provincia = input("Ingrese el nombre de la provincia nueva:")
        self.contagiosDiarios = input("Ingrese el numero de contagios diarios:")
        self.contagiosTotales = input("Ingrese el numero de contagios totales:")
        self.contagiosActivos = input("Ingrese el numero de contagios activos:")
        self.muertesTotales = input("Ingrese el numero de muertes totales:")
        self.muertesDiarias = input("Ingrese el numero de muertes diarias:")
        self.vacunasAplicadas = input("Ingrese el numero de vacunas aplicadas:")
        self.vacunasSinAplicar = input("Ingrese el numero de vacunas sin aplicar:")
        self.vacunasTotales = input("Ingrese el numero de vacunas totales:")
        f = open('covid.txt', 'r')
        for e in f.readlines():
            posicion = e[1]
        numero = int(max(posicion)) + 1
        f = open ('covid.txt','a')
        f.write('\n' + 'p' + str(numero) + ':')
        f.write(self.provincia + '|')
        f.write(self.contagiosTotales + '|')
        f.write(self.contagiosDiarios + '|')
        f.write(self.contagiosActivos + '|')
        f.write(self.muertesTotales + '|')
        f.write(self.muertesDiarias + '|')
        f.write(self.vacunasAplicadas + '|')
        f.write(self.vacunasSinAplicar + '|')
        f.write(self.vacunasTotales)
        f.close()
    def imprimir(self):
        print("Nombre de la provincia:" + self.nombre + "Contagios totales:" + self.contagiosTotales + "Contagios Diarios:" + self.contagiosDiarios + "Contagios activos:" + self.contagiosActivos + "Muertes totales:" + self.muertesTotales + "Muertes diarias:" + self.muertesDiarias + "Vacunas aplicadas:" + self.vacunasAplicadas + "Vacunas sin aplicar:" + self.vacunasSinAplicar + "Vacunas totales:" + self.vacunasTotales)


def inicio():
    while True:
        print("1)Pais con mas contagios totales")
        print("2)Pais con mas contagios diarios")
        print("3)Pais con mas contagios activos")
        print("4)Pais con mas muertes totales")
        print("5)Pais con mas muertes diarias")
        print("6)Pais con mas vacunas aplicadas")
        print("7)Pais con mas vacunas sin aplicar")
        print("8)Pais que posee mas vacunas")
        print("9)Provincia con mas contagios totales")
        print("10)Provincia con mas contagios diarios")
        print("11)Provincia con mas contagios activos")
        print("12)Provincia con mas muertes totales")
        print("13)Provincia con mas muertes diarias")
        print("14)Provincia con mas vacunas aplicadas")
        print("15)Provincia con mas vacunas sin aplicar")
        print("16)Provincia que posee mas vacunas")
        print("17)Agregar muertos")
        print("18)Agregar un nuevo lote de vacunas")
        print("19)Agregar una nueva provincia")
        print("20)Agregar un pais nuevo")
        print("21)Ver todos los paises en el mundo")
        print("22)Ver las provincias de un pais")
        print("23)Ver las provincias de todos los paises ordenadas de forma alfabetica")
        print("24)Inversiones")
        print("0) Salir")
        numeroIngresado = int(input("Ingrese el numero que desea:"))
        if numeroIngresado == 19:
            Provincia.agregarProvincia()
            break
        if numeroIngresado == 9:
            Provincia.contagiosTotales()
            break
        if numeroIngresado == 0:
            break
inicio()
```

El problema lo tengo en la funcion contagiosTotales() de la clase Provincia(Pais). Espero que se entienda la pregunta y sino pregunten lo que no se entendio en los comentarios.
El txt contiene lo siguiente:

```
p1:a|12|1234|12|12|12|12|12|12
p2:b|12|12345|12|12|12|12|12|12
```

Lo que esto quiere decir es que si el usuario ingresa a, el programa devuelve 1234. Y si el usuario ingresa b, el programa devuelve 12345. Para poder hacer eso hay que validar que verdaderamente existe una provincia con nombre a (la a la ingresa el usuario) y apartir de eso mostrar en pantalla en numero que corresponde

Comment: Sigues con el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno te puedes ahorrar un ciclo for, ya que en donde se evalua la expresion regular tambien se valida si la provincia existe.

```py
    def contagiosTotales():
        ...
        provincia = input("Ingrese el nombre de la provincia que desea:")
        for e in f:
            provincias.append(e)
            print("Agregado")
        f.close()
        regex = re.compile(r'\|(\w+\d+)+?')
        for prov in provincias:
            if provincia in prov:
                print("Es verdadero")
                casos = re.findall(regex, prov)
                casos = sum([ int(caso) for caso in casos])
                print(casos)
            else:
                print("No existe")
```

Prácticamente haces una doble validación (y mal) ya que al obtener el total ya se está validando si la provincia ya esta existe y le imprimimos "Es verdadero" y luego sumamos los casos, de lo contrario imprime "No existe".